# Read .txt file from anywhere on the phone

Tags: android

In my app I have this code allowing the user to select a file :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("text/plain");
startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

The user can select the .txt file from anywhere in his phone, even from google drive. When the file selection is done I retrieve a Uri object corresponding to the file. The problem is I can't use this Uri to read the file because it is not valid. Here is my code :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();

                    File file = new File(uri.toString());

                    try{
                        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                        int content;
                        while ((content = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                            Log.d("===>", String.valueOf((char) content));
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        Log.d("===>", e.toString());
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

I always get a fileNotFoundException. My question is, is there a way to read the selected file (without knowing in advance the location it will come from). And if not, is there a way to copy the selected file in a folder from which I would easily get it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is I can't use this Uri to read the file because it is not valid.

That is because a `Uri` is not a file.

> is there a way to read the selected file (without knowing in advance the location it will come from)

The user did not select a file. The user selected a piece of content.

To consume the content represented by the `Uri`, call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in the `Uri`. This gives you an `InputStream` that you can use to read in the content.

Comment: I just had a look at the contentProvider documentation and to be honest I don't really understand what I should do. Should I create a class extending from the contentProvider class ?

Comment: @Mtoypc: Sorry, I meant `ContentResolver` -- I have fixed my answer. Call `getContentResolver()` on any handy `Context`, such as the `Activity`. Then, call `openInputStream()` on the `ContentResolver`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me twice today